# Using python-dotenv inside a PyQGIS script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm automating my workflow using PyQGIS and I'd like to incorporate environment variables to it, as I have it in a git repository and I don't want it to detect a change every time I change a variable.

My script takes a directory and performs operations with the files in that directory, so I'll be changing that variable a lot. I decided to use an .env file for that purpose.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from os.path import join, dirname


dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

MY_VAR = os.environ.get('MY_VAR')
```

That's the error that is throwing QGIS when I execute my code in the Python interpreter:

```
exec(Path('D:/path/to/my/script.py').read_text())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

I've also tried installing python-dotenv in my QGIS python environment with

```
& 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.3\apps\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe' install python-dotenv
```

But I get

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.3\apps\qgis\python;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.3\apps\qgis\python\plugins;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.3\apps\qt5\plugins;C:\Program Files\QG
IS 3.34.3\apps\gdal\share\gdal'
  program name = 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.3\bin\python3.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS33~1.3\\bin\\python3.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS33~1.3\\bin\\python3.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.34.3\\apps\\qgis\\python',
    'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.34.3\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins',
    'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.34.3\\apps\\qt5\\plugins',
    'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.34.3\\apps\\gdal\\share\\gdal',
    'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS33~1.3\\bin\\python39.zip',
    'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS33~1.3\\bin',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000036d8 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Answer (score 2):

QGIS brings its own Python on Windows so you need to install the `dotenv` module in your QGIS' Python environment.

E.g.

1. Launch `C:/Program Files/QGIS.../OSGeo4W.bat`
2. Enter `python -m pip install dotenv`

Comment: That's what I tried using
```
& 'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.3\apps\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe' install python-dotenv
```
but I can't get it to install.

Comment: That only launches the pip.exe. It would not know about the QGIS Python environmental but install to the global one. Yeah, it's not easy ;D I'll add info to my answer.